# Deleting unused tags

Tags: tags

Tags are used to categorize blog post topics.

How can I delete or manage unused tags?

For example, one user created a "Success Factors" tag and another created a "SAP SuccessFactors" tag. The goal is to remove one of these to keep the categories tight.

Answer (score 6):

There currently isn't any Tag management in Craft, but if you think there should be, consider voting for [this feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7179221-tag-management).

In the meantime, there is a 3rd party plugin called [Tag Manager](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/tag-manager) that will let you delete tags, although it won't show you which ones aren't in use.

There is a [help article](https://craftcms.com/support/active-tags) that shows how to select all of the tags that are in use.  From there you could diff it with the full tag list to see the ones that aren't in use.